# Celery/SQS error "No module named sqs"

Tags: python, flask, celery, amazon-sqs

I am unable to configure Celery to use SQS. I followed the instructions on this link: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html

Here is the stack trace.

> [2018-02-21 12:27:25,073: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'sqs'",) 12:27:25 worker.1 | Traceback (most recent call last): 12:27:25 worker.1 | File "/Users/logan/.virtualenvs/dolittle/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in **get** 12:27:25 worker.1 | return obj.**dict**[self.**name**] 12:27:25 worker.1 | KeyError: 'backend'

I'm using Python 3.6.

Dependencies:

```
boto==2.46.1
celery==4.0.2
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It's using SQS as a result backend as well. You can set `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None`, for example.

Comment: but what if you want to receive on that sqs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `celery[sqs]` as per the new documentation:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html

When installing via PIP, if you have the following issue:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'

Install the libcurl devel packages:

Debian based :

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Centos/Fedora :

```
dnf install libcurl-devel
```